# Editing rc.local for Ubuntu Core

Tags: filesystem, ubuntu-core, read-only

I am trying to create a startup script on Ubuntu Core to enable `usb_modeswitch` to change the mode of one of the devices connected to the device. I am running Ubuntu Core on the Dragonboard410c.

As in classic Ubuntu desktops, I tried editing `/etc/rc.local`

However, even though I do `sudo vi /etc/rc.local` I can't edit `rc.local` as it complains that it is only a read-only file.

I tried editing the file directly from the SD card (This works for configuration files on netplan), but somehow `rc.local` is not visible in the SD card.

How are you supposed to use apt style packages on boot on Ubuntu Core. Do I need to create a separate snap for this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I recommend that you **[edit]** this to include information about *what errors, specifically* have happened. Please describe exactly what actions you took, including *how* you tried to edit `rc.local`, and exactly what the error was. If you don't remember it in full then you should try to reproduce it; if you're not able to reproduce it but it still doesn't work, then you can describe what possibly other wrong thing happened instead. Right now I don't think this can really be answered -- we don't know what you've actually tried to do or what prevented it from working.

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks, I have edited my question. Hope it is clearer

Answer (score 1):

Check if your root filesystem is mounted with read-write permissions ( via `/etc/mountab` or `/etc/fstab` ). Read-only filesystem won't allow editing files on it, i.e. it may not be the file problem itself.

If it is read-only, use `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` command. Note that snappy core, iirc, is meant to be a read only filesystem for security reasons

Comment: Doesn't work: `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`. Errors with:  `mount: cannot remount /dev/root read-write, is write-protected`

Comment: Check the filesystem. When SD cards say write protected it may be sign of corrupt filesystem. As for mount command it is a standard approach, works in 99% cases, so there has to be something unusual about your case

Comment: Id recommend creating a new question specifically for that on the site

Comment: @sergiykoloyazhnyy  No SD card. Looks like it's an Ubuntu Core design "feature".

Comment: Alright. Might be something changed since the past year when this was posted. Still, please post a question on the site. Someone may clarify if it is in fact Ubuntu Core's particular design or something unusual

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't write to ***/etc/rc.local*** is found in the `mount` command's output (truncated here).

```
/dev/mmcblk0p4 on /writable type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/loop0 on / type squashfs (ro,relatime)
```

Ubuntu Core mounts the root filesystem as ***squashfs*** which is read-only.  ***Parts*** of the filesystem are mounted as ***rw*** as you'll see in non-truncated output of the `mount` command, however ***rc.local*** doesn't live on one of these.

### HOW TO GET AROUND THE PROBLEM:

Firstly, ***rc.local*** is a legacy ***sysvinit*** file which has been supplanted by ***SystemD*** which is now default in Ubuntu and every other distro.

So you can't execute a script by calling it from ***rc.local*** because it's ***ro***. A better- and more granular way of raising services on boot- is to use a SystemD Timer.  This has the advantage of raising services relative to other services.  It's a ***scalpel*** vs sysvinit's rc.local ***machete***.

To execute the script at a precise point in the boot use a ***SystemD Timer***. A specimen script is shown below; tweak to your specific use-case

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF> /etc/systemd/system/myscript.service
[Unit]
Description=Customise Networking
Requires=network-online.target
After=snap.wifi-ap.management-service.service

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/myuser/scripts/myscript.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

EOF

chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/myscript.service

systemctl enable myscript.service
```

**This has been tested and proven to raise the custom service I created at the desired point in the boot and survives a reboot.**  HTH-